# how to retrieve data form the server in angular

Tags: angular, nestjs, angular-fullstack, rest

I'm trying to build my first web application using angular and Nestjs. when I try to get data from the server error was shown in the browser console. any help with that please.

```
core.js:4081 ERROR TypeError: this.books is not iterable
    at SafeSubscriber._next (book.service.ts:23)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
    at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:33)
    at FilterSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:72)
```

angular

book.service.ts

```
 import { Book } from './book.model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BookService {
  private books: Book[] = [];
  private booksUpdated = new Subject<Book[]>();

 
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
   }


  getBooks(){
    this.http.get<{books:Book[]} >('http://localhost:3000/books')
    .subscribe((bookData) =>{
      this.books = bookData.books;
      this.booksUpdated.next([...this.books]);
    });
  }

  getBookUpdateListener(){
    return this.booksUpdated.asObservable();
  }

  addBook( book_name: string, author: string){
    const book: Book = {book_ref_no: null, book_name: book_name, author: author, category: null};
    this.books.push(book);
    this.booksUpdated.next([...this.books]);
  }

  
}
```

response from the server

```
[{"book_ref_no":4,"book_name":"ice and fire","author":"jrr martine","category":"HISTORY"}]
```

can anyone please help me to fix this. please tell me the provided data is not enough to figure out a solution,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to **Angular** and **NestJS**.

Your backend controller's response seems to be:

```
[
 { book 1...},
 { book 2...},
 ...
]
```

So you should simply type your `HttpClient.get` response as `Book[]`.

```
getBooks(){
  this.http.get<Book[]>('http://localhost:3000/books').subscribe(books => {
      this.books = books;
      this.booksUpdated.next(books);
    });
  }
```

Comment: can you help me with this kind of [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63215895/extracting-data-from-responses-in-anguar/63216842?noredirect=1#comment111787928_63216842)