# extracting data from responses in anguar

Tags: angular, typescript, pagination

I was trying to get a list of items from the server. then I add pagination to the system and the response from the server change like this,

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "book_ref_no": 12,
            "book_name": "ice and fire",
            "author": "jrr martine",
            "category": "HISTORY",
            "availability": false
        },
        {
            "book_ref_no": 14,
            "book_name": "word war 2",
            "author": "Not me",
            "category": "NOVEL",
            "availability": false
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "totalItems": 4,
        "itemCount": 2,
        "itemsPerPage": "2",
        "totalPages": 2,
        "currentPage": 1
    },
    "links": {
        "first": "http://localhost:3000/books?limit=2",
        "previous": "",
        "next": "http://localhost:3000/books?page=2&limit=2",
        "last": "http://localhost:3000/books?page=2&limit=2"
    }
}
```

can someone help me to extract items, meta and links from this response in angular. previously i used below code to extract data from the request. but at that time the response was quait differant.

```
getBooks(){
      this.http.get<Book[]>('http://localhost:3000/books')
      .subscribe(books => {
          this.books = books;
          this.booksUpdated.next(books);
        },
        );
      }
```

previous response was like

```
[
 { book 1...},
 { book 2...},
 ...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try like this.
First create an interface that defines the response.

```
interface Book{
  book_ref_no: number,
  book_name: string,
  author: string,
  category: string, // or Enum
  availability: boolean
}

interface Meta{
  totalItems: number,
  itemCount: number,
  itemsPerPage: string,
  totalPages: number,
  currentPage: number
}

interface Links{
  first: string,
  previous: string,
  next: string,
  last: string
}

interface PagedResponse{
  items: Book[],
  meta: Meta,
  links: Links
}
```

Then you can just grab the books from that response like,

```
getBooks(){
    this.http.get<PagedResponse>('http://localhost:3000/books')
      .subscribe(pagedResponse => {
          this.books = pagedResponse.items;
        },
      );
  }
```

Comment: @Just_Run pleasure it was helpful. Its better to learn some Typescript basics; also your question is nothing to do with angular. Because typescript cares much about types! So above it cared much about the type of the response :D

Answer (score 1):

First update your interface

```
interface Book{ 
book_ref_no: number, book_name: string, 
author: string, 
category: string,
 availability: boolean }

 interface Meta{ 
totalItems: number, 
itemCount: number,
 itemsPerPage: string, 
totalPages: number, 
currentPage: number }

 interface Links{ first: string,
 previous: string, 
next: string, 
last: string } 

interface BooksResponse{ 
items: Book[], 
meta: Meta, 
links: Links }
```

Then use the BooksResponse as the return type of your api

```
getBooks(){ 
        this.http.get<BooksResponse>('http://localhost:3000/books')
         .subscribe(data => { 
 this.books = data.items;
    
     this.booksUpdated.next(this.books);
    
         }, ); 
        }
```

Comment: I need to extract items from the response and assign them to the books list. can you help me to extract them? The above code have some errors.

Comment: shouldn't `get<Book[]>` change. because the response is not just a book list now.

Comment: threre is a red underline below `items` in `this.books = data.items;`

Comment: Try add any type to data=>.subscribe((data:any) => {

Comment: Property `'items'` does not exist on type `'Book[]'`

Comment: the topmost response is the response from the server. I think there is an error in `get<Book[]>`. but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Can you please share the Book interface. Items property is missing in that.

Comment: previously response was just a list of books, that's why I used `this.http.get<Book[]>`. but right now the response is not just a list of books. it contains some other information also.

Comment: `export interface Book{
    book_ref_no: number;
    book_name: string;
    author: string;
    category: BookCategeries;
    availability: boolean;
    
}`

Comment: Then you have to update the books interface first or use any type or call the get() method without specifying the return type

Comment: in the response `items` represent instances of book. it is not a property of the Book

Comment: That i know. this.http.get<Book[]>, here Books is the return type of this api. That is wrong. It should have items of type Books array, meta and links

Comment: how can I do that

Comment: no. now another error. `Property 'items' does not exist on type 'Object'.`

Comment: Only thing was u need the updated interface. Use http://json2ts.com to create interface. You just need to paste the json it will give u the model.